# what is the key different between ASP.NET 2008 with Web developer express 2008?

Tags: asp.net

// question has been modified

I start to learn ASP.NET and the book uses Web developer express 2008 as the development platform.
I would like to know what the key difference between using the professional VS 2008 and this free express version.

Thank you

Comment: Key differences between developing ASP.NET web applications using Visual Studio 2008 Express and **what**?

Comment: The question isn't making sense because asp.net 2008 is something you do with Web Developer Express 2008.  It's like asking "What's the difference between fishing with my dad?"  A sensible question would be "What's the difference between Asp.net 2008 with Web Developer Express 2008 and Asp.Net 2008 with Visual Studio 2008 Professional?" - more like "what's the difference between fishing with my dad and fishing with my uncle?"

Comment: I have changed my question. thank you

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net is the platform.  Web Developer Express is an IDE that allows you to write code for the asp.net platform...

There are several [Visual Studio versions](http://www.microsoft.com/vstudio), all of which can be used to write code in any of the .Net languages (C#, VB, etc) as well as targeting WinForms or web applications (asp.net).